# Customise tabular reports with Bugzilla

Tags: bugzilla

I want add more columns to the tabular report.
I am using bugzilla version 4.2.5.
Can you please help with the files that i have to do modification to?

Thanks,
Ramya

Answer (score 3):

if the required field is not there in column list("Change Columns") we have to add the new field by editing the following files.

```
1)colchange.cgi
2)list/change-columns.html.tmpl
3)field-descs.none.tmpl
```

All the coloumns of the buglist are directly taken from the DB fields.
For eg:
ID of the buglist page is directly taken from the field bug_id of table bugs.

- New fields can be added and arranged the order in which they have to
  display in the file colchange.cgi.
- Corresponding template file of colchange.cgi is
  list/change-columns.html.tmpl.
- If we need any modification in the change coloumn page we have to
  modify the template file list/change-columns.html.tmpl.
- New fields added should be defined in the file field-descs.none.tmpl.

Modify the following files:

```
1)buglist.cgi
2)colchange.cgi
3)field-descs.none.tmpl
```

- Added the corresponding coloumn to be displayed in the file colchange.cgi and pass the variables to the template file list/list.html.tmpl.
- Defined the name that should be displayed in front end in the file
  field-descs.none.tmpl.
- Modify the file buglist.cgi for the query that should give the
  value for the    corresponding field

.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.

1. When you display a report, you will find a link at the bottom that says "Change Columns". That's the wasiest way.
2. If you wan tot change the default columns the edit the following statement in /usr/local/bugzilla-4.2.5/Bugzilla/Constants.pm and add or remove default columns.

   use constant DEFAULT_COLUMN_LIST => (
           "product", "component", "assigned_to",
           "bug_status", "resolution", "short_desc", "changeddate"
       );

**EDIT:** Just realized that this question is two years old. I hope that it helps someone else who stumbles on it.